# Icons for audio controller and recycle bean

Tags: android

I've a program running that does record, play, pause, stop, delete.
I've crated my own icons that looks ok but not great and consistent with the android look and feel.
I've googled but can't find nice simple icons.

do you guys have recommendations where to look?

why does the studio not provide such simple icons as it does for the zoom control?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically search google for free icons and make sure they dont have any legal issues or burdening liscence.
here are few locations:

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

http://roundicons.com/

http://allthefreestock.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've reviewed the 4 sites + spent a lot of time googling, but cannot find standard icons. I understand that value added icons are propriatary but standard simple icons like what I mention should be provided as default? It would help for apps consistency.

Comment: @narb sorry man, the things google provides are contained here https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html now i assume you didnt find what you look for in here so you should look for other icons, and while most apps UI usually has a certain flavour those change with time and they dont all keep the same icons just the same "general feel" take one of the icon from those icon sets and so long as its not extravagant you should be ok, other than that im not familiar with anythnig beter (btw looking for android default icon sets will yield icon sets so your app will be consistant)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks! I am jut missing the bin. but there are a lot of stuff to review si I may find what I'm looking for :)

Comment: the funny part is that I had the developper.android zip file but not sur why I was not happy at that time :)